# Concurrent request handling in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, concurrency

I have a issue of concurrent request, which modifies db.

What am I doing is.
One request fetch data for user-1 , then calculate data for user-1 modified a field-1 in record, and save.

next request fetch data for user-1 , then calculate data for user-1 modified a field-1 in record, and save.

Both request operates simultaneously. so last request update the wrong data.

```js
function calculate() {
  var needUpdate = false;
  user = new UserLib(user_id);
  var old_config = user.config;
  if (old_config[req.id]) {
    old_config[req.id].value = 0;
    needUpdate = true;
  }
  if (req.delete == void(0) || req.delete == false) {
    delete req.delete;
    old_config[req.id].value = old_config[req.id].value + 1;
    needUpdate = true;
  }
  if (needUpdate) {
    return user.save();
  }
  return true;
}
```

[image]

We are getting both requests at the same time.

```js
  var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/update', function(req, res) {

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
  });


  calculate(req);

  function calculate(req) {

    var needUpdate = false;

    user = new UserLib(user_id);
    var old_config = user.config;

    if (old_config[req.id]) {
      old_config[req.id].value = 0;
      needUpdate = true;
    }

    if (req.delete == void(0) || req.delete == false) {
      delete req.delete;
      old_config[req.id].value = old_config[req.id].value + 1;
      needUpdate = true;
    }

    if (needUpdate) {
      user.save();
    }
  }

  res.end('Done');
});
first reuest with following parameter {
  user_id: 1,
  id: 1,
  value: 5,
  delete: false
}

Anothere request with follwing parmter {
  user_id: 1,
  id: 1,
  delete: true
}
```

Comment: What library are you using to control flows? Promises or [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)?

Comment: We are using bluebird

Comment: Actually this is something that can not be handle by promisification i think. if you have any solution regarding this, it will be appreciating.

Comment: Wrong, everything can be handled through promisification. Could you give me a piece of code to work with? I'm writing a general answer for now.

Comment: function calculate() {

 var needUpdate = false;

 user = new UserLib(user_id);
 var old_config = user.config;

 if(old_config[req.id]) {
     old_config[req.id].value = 0;
     needUpdate = true;
 }

 if(req.delete == void(0) || req.delete == false){
  delete req.delete;
     old_config[req.id].value = old_config[req.id].value + 1;
     needUpdate = true;
 }

 if(needUpdate) {
  return user.save();
 }
 return true;
}

Comment: Actually both request are independent both request fetch the data from user simultaneuosly, so both have same initial user record.

Comment: first request : var req1 = {user_id : 1, id:1, value : 5, delete : false};
second reuest var req2 = {user_id : 1, id:1, delete : true};

Comment: second request do nothing and exit but first request set the data. but it should be sync that user think that he set the value and then delete the value, but in db result is value is setted.

Comment: I added a second example that could do the job

Answer (score 1):

If you want to operate on each request simultaneously, I'd suggest to use `Bluebird.map` where you can handle each request as you want, with concurrency, and a final result.

For example:

```
let users = ['foo', 'bar']; //fetching users you want

Bluebird.map(users, (user) => {
   return user.calculate()
   .then((res) => res.shouldUpdate ? user.save() : Promise.resolve())
}, {concurrency: 2})
.then((results) => {
  //results is an array with both resolved promises from below
})
```

You may also be interested in [`Bluebird.join`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html) where you could calculate, and join the resulting data for more than one promise.

Second example where you fetch same user twice in the same promise:

```
//both are promises
Bluebird.all([fetchUser1, fetchUser2])
.spread(function(user1, user2) {
   //check if should update
   return user1.delete !== user2.delete ? user.delete() : null
})
.then(() => {})
```

[Bluebird.spread documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html)

Comment: Actually function is to update a user's data based on previous state. let's say all happens promisified, first fetch then update then return. But point is that both server request are independent, that have nothing to do with promisification.

Comment: I don't see how your requests could not be promise-based. `fetchUser1` doesn't have to be a promise, it can be your old user. Where `fetchUser2` is the request.